# bracket pair can't match in mac vscode txt file

Tags: visual-studio-code, text

I want to highlight and jump(command+shift+\) between the bracket pair in text file just like in json files and other format files.
Please help me,thx!

[image]
[image]

And the vscode info is:

```
Version: 1.67.1 (Universal)
Commit: da15b6fd3ef856477bf6f4fb29ba1b7af717770d
Date: 2022-05-06T12:37:16.526Z
Electron: 17.4.1
Chromium: 98.0.4758.141
Node.js: 16.13.0
V8: 9.8.177.13-electron.0
OS: Darwin x64 19.6.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by change the vscode version to

```
Version: 1.66.2
Commit: dfd34e8260c270da74b5c2d86d61aee4b6d56977
Date: 2022-04-11T07:49:20.994Z
Electron: 17.2.0
Chromium: 98.0.4758.109
Node.js: 16.13.0
V8: 9.8.177.11-electron.0
OS: Darwin x64 19.6.0
```

So It looks like a bug in 1.67.1 (Universal)